# Flutter : reading of 50k rows of data in excel in flutter when it loads. Do I have better ways to make it faster?

Tags: excel, database, flutter, caching, dart

I'm new to Flutter.

I have 20 excel(extension is .xlsx) files which have 50k rows total to read when my app is loaded. It takes a few seconds to read them everytime. I think it is not that efficient way to read data from xlsx files.

I want to know if it's more efficient to read from database or use cache instead of reading 50k rows of records from spreadsheet.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Can you please tell your use case? I mean why do you need to read all these rows in memory each time app starts?

Comment: I saved data in spreadsheets about some events which is seen as date, the description of event each row. It's up to 50,000 events and Flutter shows them in ListView after read all the records from spreadsheets. I just thought it's easy to edit with excel. I could do a better way if I knew it.

Comment: wait, you want to show up to 50000 events in one simple `ListView`? are you sure your users are prepared for such huge data? who would want to scroll such a monster list? cannot you group it by some time period or something else?

Comment: You can fetch it from server.. Also fetch 10 events each time may be. So when user scrolls at the bottom, fetch next 10 events and so on..

Comment: @pskink Yes, you are right. I tried to make the app user can search with keywords in the monster list regardless time period...your suggestion can be an alternative if it's too much burden on the single ListView. I'm trying to figure out how the items can be seen in the single ListView.

Comment: @AmitB10 That's a great idea but the app should be working without data usage. It's the app for students who study history stuff. Some of them may want to turn off the data usage to avoid distractions when they study. Thank you for the suggestion tho!

Comment: Ohh okay.. Can you do something like this then : rather than excels, use sqlite. Use sqflite package. And then query 10 events each time?

Comment: @AmitB10 That makes sense. I want to know more in detail about 'each time'.  It's like query db whenever I scroll down in the ListView? How do I implement that?

Comment: Take a look at https://pub.dev/packages/infinite_listview this package

Comment: Have a look at this article as well.. https://www.developerlibs.com/2018/11/flutter-infinite-scroll-or-load-more.html?m=1

Comment: Thank you so much. I guess then I can’t get search result from far bottom of ListView since it isn’t loaded yet?